# How to efficiently find the minimal difference of sums of triplets in an array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o, combinations, combinatorics

I have an array of numbers `int arr[] = {4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 4, 7, 3, 5};`
and I need to find the 3 triplets (they don't need to be consecutive) in which their (the triplet's) sum difference is minimal ('closest sums').

**clarifications:**
Each number may only appear the times it appears in the original array (i.e `{{4, 7, 8}, {9, 2, 4}, {7, **4**, 5}}` isn't ok because 4 has appeared only twice in the input.)

You may assume that the array is sorted.
The triplets **don't have to be in consecutive order.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Define "triplet". Would that be three consecutive numbers of the array?

Comment: may be try sorting array and average of last three number would be max average?

Comment: the maximum average is the one taken with the 3 maximum elements, sort the array and take the first 3 elements

Comment: @DirkR they dont have to be consecutive.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'm looking for the maximal average of 3 triplets, not just one triplet.

Comment: then take the first 9 numbers in the sorted array. It is unclear what you are looking for. Please include an example. Also what did you try? How did it fail? "Any ideas?" isnt really a specific quesiton

Comment: What is a triplet sum difference? E.g., if triplets are (a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i), are you looking to minimize |(a+b+c)-(d+e+f)| + |(a+b+c)-(g+h+i)| + |(d+e+f)-(g+h+i)|? Or something else?

Comment: @Dave Exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is not simple. We need to deal with "combinations". Please read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). As a result, we can get big numbers, which makes calculations difficult.

Some basics. A triplet consists of 3 values. The source array has 9 values. We want to get triplets that fullfil a certain condition.

If we look at a number with 9 digits, we could get all possible triplets by calculating all permutations of the array with 9 values and take always index 0,1,2 and 3,4,5 and 6,7,8. Then we would get automatically all triplets. But also many doubles and not-distinct unwanted triplets. Overall 362880 permutations. Also doable and no problem for a computer nowadays.

We will go a different way, we will calculate the real combinations which are then 9 choose 3 = 84.

There are many algorithms published, how to generate all combinations, all based on the same principle. We will create a boolean array that consists of k = 3 values beeing true. Then we build all permutations of this boolean array. Each permutation will always have 3 bool values that are true. Example:

```
000000111
000001011
000001101
. . .
```

So, easy to understand.

And for all these permutations of the boolean array, we check, at which position the value is true and select a source value with the same index. Then we have guaranteed a triplet. And we will get all triplets. For

```
{ 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 4, 7, 3, 5 }
-->
000000111 --> 7 3 5
000001011 --> 4 3 5
000001101 --> 4 7 5
. . .
```

That is the general mechanism. Now, next, we should select 3 distinct triplets out of these found 84 triplets.

Distinct means, no position is used double. So all positions from the origninal array must be present. We can check distinction by comparing all values with all other values for 2 triplets. And, similar with 3 triplets.

Next, we need to select all groups consisting of 3 triplets out of the already found 84 triplets. That is again a combination. So, 84 choose 3 = 95284 possible groups. However, as said, the 3 triplets of one group must be distinct.

If we check this, then just 280 groups are left for further evaluation.

```
(9 choose 3) * (6 choose 3) / 3! = 84 * 20 / 6 = 280
```

First, we select one triplet. 6 numbers are remaining. Then we select 3 values from the remaining 6, then 3 values are left. But, for the left triplet, we have all permutations, so, get rid of the permutations and devide by 3! = 6.

Because we want to find special groups, where their sums need to fullfil a certain condition, we calculate the sums of all triplets in the groups.

For the distance we look at the sums. For example: If we have the a group with the triplets and sums:

```
2 3 5-->10    7 4 7-->18    4 8 9-->21

10-------18---21

Distance 1: 8    18-10
Distance 2: 3    21-18
Dinstance overall=: 21-10 = 11
```

So, we simply calculate MaxSum - MinSum and call this distance. We do this for all groups of triplets.

Then we sort the result, and the minimum distance will be at the beginning of the resulting data. We will get then for example:

```
4 7 5-->16    7 8 2-->17    4 9 3-->16
Distance: 1
```

Please note additionally. In order to be not confused with the real numbers, we calculate with indices into the source array as long as possible. For most calculations the source array data is completely irrelevant. Just for calculating the sums, we need them.

See below the complete and well commented example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>

using Triplet = std::array<int, 3>;

// Constexpr function to calculate the factorial
constexpr unsigned long fact(unsigned int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1; else return n * fact(n - 1);
};
// Constexpr function to calculate n choose k, and here specifically n choose 3
constexpr unsigned long NCR3(int n) {
    return fact(n) / ( 6 * fact(n - 3));
};

int main() {

    // The source data
    int arr[] = { 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 4, 7, 3, 5 };

    // Get the number of source data
    constexpr size_t NumberOfSourceValues = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    // For calculating the combinations, we build a bool array with 3 bools set to true
    // and the rund all permutations for these 3 bools. So we will get all combinations
    // of a bool array with 3 true values
    std::array<bool, NumberOfSourceValues> selectors1{};
    static_assert(NumberOfSourceValues > 3, "\nError: Not enough source Values\n");
    selectors1[NumberOfSourceValues - 1] = true;
    selectors1[NumberOfSourceValues - 2] = true;
    selectors1[NumberOfSourceValues - 3] = true;

    // This is the result of 9 choose 3. It is 84. We will get that number of combinations
    constexpr size_t NumberOfTriplets = NCR3(NumberOfSourceValues);

    // Here we will store the 84 (9 choose 3) resulting combinations
    static std::array<Triplet, NumberOfTriplets> triplets{}; // Static --> Put on heap

    // Counter and index for storing the result
    size_t permutationCounter{};
    do {
        Triplet triplet{};  // Temporary triplet
        size_t indexInTriplet{};
        // Go through all bool values in our bool array
        for (size_t indexInBoolArray{}; indexInBoolArray < NumberOfSourceValues; ++indexInBoolArray)

            // If a bool is set in the bool array, then copy the INDEX of our indicesArray
            if (selectors1[indexInBoolArray]) triplet[indexInTriplet++] = indexInBoolArray;;

        // So, we found 3 indices (Guaranteed, because 3 bools are true always). Copy that to our result
        triplets[permutationCounter++] = std::move(triplet);

        // Calculate the next permutation
    } while (std::next_permutation(selectors1.begin(), selectors1.end()));

    // Array for goups of 3 triplets that are distinct (have no already used number)
    constexpr size_t NumberOfTripletGoups = NCR3(9) * NCR3(6) / 6;  // 6 = fact(3)
    static std::array<std::array<Triplet, 3>, NumberOfTripletGoups> distinctTripletGroups{}; // Static --> Put on heap

    // We want to again calculate combinations, n chooes k
    // So, we will have an array of 84 bools with the last 3 values true
    static std::array<bool, NumberOfTriplets> selectors2{};
    static_assert(NumberOfTriplets > 3, "\nError: Not enough triplets found\n");
    selectors2[NumberOfTriplets - 1] = true;
    selectors2[NumberOfTriplets - 2] = true;
    selectors2[NumberOfTriplets - 3] = true;

    // Please note: this loop will run 84 choose 3: 95384 times
    // But we will only use 280 distinct values
    size_t groupCounter{};
    do {
        std::array<Triplet, 3> tripletGroup{};
        size_t k{};
        for (size_t i{}; i < NumberOfTriplets; ++i) {
            if (selectors2[i]) {
                tripletGroup[k++] = triplets[i];
            }
        }
        // Check for distinct (not double) values in all 3 triplets of a triplet group.
        // Compare every value with all other values
        bool distinct = true;
        for (size_t ii{}; distinct && (ii < 3); ++ii) for (size_t kk{}; distinct && (kk < 3); ++kk) {
            distinct = distinct && (tripletGroup[0][ii] != tripletGroup[1][kk]);
            distinct = distinct && (tripletGroup[0][ii] != tripletGroup[2][kk]);
            distinct = distinct && (tripletGroup[1][ii] != tripletGroup[2][kk]);
        }
        // If the triplets are distinct, then we add the triplet group to the result
        if (distinct) {
            distinctTripletGroups[groupCounter++] = (std::move(tripletGroup));
        }
        // Next triplet goup selection
    } while (std::next_permutation(selectors2.begin(), selectors2.end()));


    // Holding the result of our distance calculations
    struct DistanceData {
        size_t threeTripletsIndex{};        // The index of the triplet group. Is in the begiining 0,1,2,3,4,5
        int distanceForThreeTriplets{};     // Distance of Triplets in triplet group
        std::array<int, 3> tripletSums{};   // Sums of single triplets in a group
    };
    static std::array<DistanceData, NumberOfTripletGoups> distanceData{}; // Static --> Put on heap

    // Calculate the distance data. Simply subtract the min sum of a triplet from the max sum of a triplet for one triplet-group
    for (size_t tripletGroup{}; tripletGroup < distinctTripletGroups.size(); ++tripletGroup) {
        for (size_t tripletIndex{}; tripletIndex < 3; ++tripletIndex)
            for (size_t indexInTriplet{}; indexInTriplet < 3; ++indexInTriplet)
                // Calculate the sum of one single triplet
                distanceData[tripletGroup].tripletSums[tripletIndex] += arr[distinctTripletGroups[tripletGroup][tripletIndex][indexInTriplet]];

        // Calculate the distannce for the three triplets
        distanceData[tripletGroup].distanceForThreeTriplets = std::max(std::max(distanceData[tripletGroup].tripletSums[0], distanceData[tripletGroup].tripletSums[1]), distanceData[tripletGroup].tripletSums[2]) -
            std::min(std::min(distanceData[tripletGroup].tripletSums[0], distanceData[tripletGroup].tripletSums[1]), distanceData[tripletGroup].tripletSums[2]);
        // And the index (Just neded for sorting later). Is alwyas equal to running loop variable
        distanceData[tripletGroup].threeTripletsIndex = tripletGroup;
    }

    // Sort result with distances, sum, and three-triplet index
    std::sort(distanceData.begin(), distanceData.end(), [](const DistanceData& d1, const DistanceData& d2) { return d1.distanceForThreeTriplets < d2.distanceForThreeTriplets; });

    // Show pretty printed output to user
    for (size_t tripletGroup{}; tripletGroup < distinctTripletGroups.size(); ++tripletGroup) {

        // Show the distance for 3 found triplets
        std::cout << std::right << std::setw(5) << tripletGroup + 1 << ".  Distance: " << std::setw(2) << distanceData[tripletGroup].distanceForThreeTriplets << '\t';

        // For each triplet in the set of 3 triplets
        for (size_t tripletIndex{}; tripletIndex < 3; ++tripletIndex) {

            // For each value of one single triplet
            for (size_t indexInTriplet{}; indexInTriplet < 3; ++indexInTriplet) {
                std::cout << arr[distinctTripletGroups[distanceData[tripletGroup].threeTripletsIndex][tripletIndex][indexInTriplet]] << " ";
            }
            // Show the sum of 1 triplet
            std::cout << "[" << std::setw(2) << distanceData[tripletGroup].tripletSums[tripletIndex] << "]\t";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

All array sizes can be compile time constants.

No dynamic memory handling is needed.